# Extension of probability space problem: Hilbert space valued process V.S. random field

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

Maybe the question should be  *"Understanding the measurability: Hilbert space valued process V.S. random field"*

Consider the SPDE $${\rm d}u+\cdots{\rm d}t=\sigma(t,u){\rm d}W.$$

Consider the Cauchy problem with $H^s$ initial data $u(0)=u_0(\omega,x)\in L^2(\Omega;H^s)$ ($H^s$ is Sobolev space), then for some $\tau>0$, there is an $\mathcal{F}_t$ predictable $H^s$-valued process $u$ such that
 $u\in C([0,\tau];H^s)$, ${\mathbb P}-a.s.$  and $u$ solves the equation almost surely. We consider the path wise solution so a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},{\mathbb P},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq0}, W)$ is **fixed in advance**.

Then we move to the global existence issue **and then the question comes**.

1. For the deterministic PDE, some conditions on $u_0$ can give a global solution. And that condition is not on the size of $\|u_0\|_{H^s}$, but on the point behavior of $u_0(x)$ (for example, $-3<\partial_xu_0<3$ for all $x$). One can say that the condition is given **when $u_0$ is viewed as a random field**.
2. To extend the deterministic results to SPDE, **how can we extent the probability space such that the solution $u$ can be also measured as a random field???** Or we need to solve the equation again when $u$ is viewed as a random field?

For example, ${\mathbb P}\{\|u\|_{H^s}<100\}$ makes sense because $u$ is a $H^s$-valued process. But ${\mathbb P}\{\partial_xu<100\}$ is **not** clear because $\{\partial_xu<100\}$ is **not** a Borel set in $H^s$ (am I right???) and can we **extent the probability space to overcome this**??

This question **also comes** when we consider the non-negativity of the solution. For example, many papers considered stochastic reaction-diffusion equations. The solution is considered as an Hilbert valued process. But the authors just suddenly assumed that ${\mathbb P}\{u_0\ge0\}=1$ and then it can be proved that ${\mathbb P}\{u\ge0\}=1$. But $\{ u_0\ge0\}$ does not belong to $\mathcal{F}_0$.

Why can we do this???

Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Depends on $s$...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time! Let us consider a good case, i.e., $s>\frac{d}{2}+1$ so that the solution is Lipschitz in $x$. Then it is right? Why? Thanks again!

Comment: Then $\{\partial_x u < 100\}$ is a perfectly fine Borel set since $u \mapsto \partial_x u(x)$ is continuous from $H^s$ to $R$ and by continuity you only need to take the supremum over the rationals, say.

Comment: Thanks for your time again! It is my honor to receive an answer from you!